# PHP Prepared Statement variable binding error with subquery

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have a query with a few subqueries like so

```
SELECT ...
FROM    (SELECT ...
         FROM ...
         GROUP BY ...) as speedLimitCalc INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT ...
        FROM date a INNER JOIN HOURLY_TEST b ON a.[FULL_DAY_DT] = b.DATE
        WHERE (b.DATE BETWEEN '".$date_s."' AND '".$date_e."') 
            AND HOUR BETWEEN ".$time_s." AND ".$time_e."
            AND(LKNO BETWEEN '".$lkno_s."' and '".$lkno_e."')
            AND RDNO= '".$rdno."'
            AND pub_hol IN (".$pubholquery.")
            AND school_hol IN (".$schholquery.")
            AND day_no IN (".$dayquery.")                                   
            GROUP BY RDNO, LKNO, PRESCRIBED_DIRECTION, CWAY_CODE)  as origtable ON ...
        ,(SELECT ...
          FROM [Dim_date]
          WHERE (FULL_DAY_DT BETWEEN '".$date_s."' AND '".$date_e."')
            AND pub_hol IN (".$pubholquery.")
            AND school_hol IN (".$schholquery.")
            AND day_no IN (".$dayquery.") ) as c
ORDER BY ...
```

where I am inserting variables in the inner query where clause.

I am trying to parametrize this query using odbc_prepare and odbc_execute, however I am running into issues of binding the variables. At present, when I use the following

```
$result = odbc_prepare($connection, $query);
odbc_execute($result)or die(odbc_error($connection));
```

to run this query, everything works fine. However, when I try to bind a variable, such as

```
AND RDNO= ?
...
odbc_execute($result, array($rdno))or die(odbc_error($connection));
```

I get the following error message.

> PHP Warning:  odbc_execute() [/phpmanual/function.odbc-execute.html]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid parameter number, SQL state S1093 in SQLDescribeParameter

My guess is that it's because I'm binding a variable in a subquery, since this procedure works when the Where clause is in the top Select query.

I was wondering whether anyone else has encountered this issue before, and how they solved it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by removing the need for parameters in the subquery by separating the query into multiple queries using temporary tables.

```
$query = "SELECT ...
          INTO ##avgspeedperlink
          FROM Date a INNER JOIN HOURLY_TEST ON a.[FULL_DAY_DT] = b.DATE 
          WHERE (b.DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?) 
            AND HOUR BETWEEN ? AND ?
            AND(LKNO BETWEEN ? and ?)
            AND RDNO= ?
            AND pub_hol IN (".$pubholquery.")
            AND school_hol IN (".$schholquery.")
            AND day_no IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
          GROUP BY RDNO, LKNO, PRESCRIBED_DIRECTION, CWAY_CODE";

$result = odbc_prepare($connection, $query);
odbc_execute($result, array($date_s,$date_e,$time_s,$time_e,$lkno_s,$lkno_e,$rdno,$daysanitised[0],$daysanitised[1],$daysanitised[2],$daysanitised[3],$daysanitised[4],$daysanitised[5],$daysanitised[6]))or die(odbc_error($connection));

$query = "SELECT ...
          INTO ##daysinperiod
          FROM [RISSxplr].[dbo].[Dim_date]
          WHERE (FULL_DAY_DT BETWEEN ? AND ?)
            AND pub_hol IN (".$pubholquery.")
            AND school_hol IN (".$schholquery.")
            AND day_no IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$result = odbc_prepare($connection, $query);
odbc_execute($result, array($date_s,$date_e,$daysanitised[0],$daysanitised[1],$daysanitised[2],$daysanitised[3],$daysanitised[4],$daysanitised[5],$daysanitised[6]))or die(odbc_error($connection));

$query = "SELECT ...
          FROM ##avgspeedperlink, ##daysinperiod
          ORDER BY LKNO, OUTBOUND

drop table ##avgspeedperlink
drop table ##daysinperiod";
```

Note that I had to use double ## for making the temporary tables (single # means that table is local to the query, ## means that the temporary table becomes global for multiple queries).